# Laurent series expansion in annulus with centre in pole

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am having a hard time expanding the function: $$ f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2(z+1)} $$
in powers of $(z-1)$ in the region $ D : 1 < |z-1| < 2 $ 
I already rewrote the function as: $$ f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2(z+1)} = \frac{1}{2(z-1)^2} - \frac{1}{4(z-1)} + \frac{1}{2(z+1)} $$ 
Now I am not sure how to turn the term $ \frac{1}{(z-1)} $ for example into a geometric series so that it converges for $ 1 < |z-1| $ or $ |z-1| < 2 $. I even found some formulas in our book (the book is in German) but using them I get a 0 in the denominator, as the centre point of the region is also a pole of my function. I would greatly appreciate any help! [image: Formulas for inner and outer expansion]

Comment: You need to consider two cases: If $|z - 1| > 1$ then $\frac{1}{|z-1|} < 1$, and similar for the other. Then use the geometric series.

Comment: The first two  terms involving $z-1$ are in the correct form. For $(z+1)^{-1}$ use $ z+1=2[(z-1)/2+1]$ and expand the reciprocal into the geometric series as $|z-1|/2<1.$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you mean that the terms including z-1 basically already are the expansion but contain just one term? Why would this be the case? Has it something to do with the fact that the centre of the region is in 1?

Comment: The terms in the Laurent expansion centered at $ 1$  are of the form $(z-1)^n$ for integer values of $n.$ The part $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$ should be convergent for $|z-1|<2.$ The part $\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}a_n(z-1)^n$ should be convergent for $|z-1|>1.$ In your case the second part consists of just two terms, so the convergence issue is irrelevant.